# Форма выдаёт результат из базы данных по введенному критерию(ям) по имеющимся совпадениям

Tags: php, html, javascript, mysql

Имеется форма (Фамилия,имя,предмет,оценка)ну и кнопка отправить. Затем *php* файл должен выдать по введенным критериям информацию из базы данных.Например ввели фамилию воро

вывелось: воронин, воробьев, воросенков

ввели например фамилию воро оценка 4 вывелись все с воро и оценкой 4

КАК это сделать?

Comment: А что у вас есть на данный момент? Есть знания PHP, как отправлять форму на сервер? Как получить значения из POST, GET массивов? Как подключиться к БД и сделать запрос?

Comment: я подключаюсь к базе,я получаю ответы с формы..но не пойму как сравнивать введенное и выдавать с базы...

Comment: Вам надо принять данные: `$name = $_POST['first_name'];`

Вам надо составить запрос в БД используя эти данные:

    $sql->setSQL("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE first_name LIKE '?%';");
   $sql->execute($name);

Comment: Буду пробывать)отпишусь

Comment: первый случай - select * from table where first_name like 'воро%'
второй случай - select * from table where first_name like 'воро%' and score = '4'

Comment: воро это пример...так то всё просто...но пользователь может ввести всё что угодно...и если такого нету никого то выдать что нет таких...а если совпадение прошло с базой то всех и вывести...

Comment: в идеале пользователь может вводить хоть одно поле хоть все четыре...я уже дня 3 думаю как это сделать. php изучаю не так давно.перерыл кучу информации а толком ничё не нашёл такого.Жду помощи тут

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментариев от [terantul](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11594/terantul)*

первый случай

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  first_name LIKE 'воро%'
```

второй случай

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  first_name
LIKE
  'воро%' AND score = '4'
```